# How to get access to specific line

Tags: c#, file

```
private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            //Finding your file and assigning it as a string.
            string start = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\file.txt";

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(start))
            {
                string line = streamReader.ReadLine();

                int[] values = line.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

                Array.Sort(values);

                Array.Reverse(values);

                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    richTextBox4.AppendText(values[i] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
```

So i need to get access to 8-9-10 lines and my .txt file is: 
https://gyazo.com/7ac43e9c5a4cb4d17393e429657778ae

Also 8-9-10 lines have to be like this:

```
28 80 62 30 68 77 71 64 54 84 57 37,
```

in one line.

Comment: It is not clear, at least not to me, what do you mean with "i need to get access to", do you have read problems to the file? Also, you should consider editing your question and adding the file sample in the question body, not as an external link.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to `Skip` first `7` lines, you can do it with a help of *Linq*:

```
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;

   ...

   private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     var numbers = File
       .ReadLines(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "file.txt"))
       .Skip(7)
    // .Take(3) // Uncomment it if you want to take at most 3 lines after skip
       .SelectMany(line => line.Split(' ')); 

     richTextBox4.Text = string.Join(" ", numbers);
   }
```

Comment: @Anu Viswan: thank you! Your suggestion - `.Take(3)` - can be very helpful if file can have more than 10 lines with data